# Validating HTML-Snippets in Java?

Tags: java, html, validation

I'm looking for a Java-library which allows me to validate HTML-Snippets like this:

```
<div class=something>
    <iframesrc="link">
```

I have see solutions to validate a whole website or ways to check if tags are written correctly, but not for validations to check for closing-tags.

Has someone an idea for that?

Kind regards

Comment: I have seen this post. As i understood it, these libs only take whole websites (<html><head>...). Because i only want to validate a snipped, it is not supported unless i add the missing tags manually every time i want to validate it... and this is a thing i realy want to avoid...

Comment: Im not sure i can help you with this but Can you check with Jsoup?

Comment: Yes this is possible. I write it as an answer and a "how to". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the lib Jsoup works here.

to use it:

```
String htmlSnippetString = "<div...";
Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.basic(); //here you define what HTML is allowed
boolean htmlTest = Jsoup.isValid(htmlSnippetString, whitelist);
```

Thanks to @soorapadman